# Using search bar and debouncing

Tags: uisearchbar, debouncing

I have properly created a search bar that implements debouncing. I created a jQuery input field that calls the function handleSearchKeyPress. This function grabs the current value by calling event.target.value and uses that value to call another "debounce" function. This debounce function then takes in a function and timeDelay as parameters and implements the general debounce pattern of clearing the current timeout value and setting a new one. This function (provided it makes it past the timeDelay) then uses the value passed in to do other stuff with. The issue I am running into is the search bar. When I type in "Hello, world!" and wait 500 ms, it uses the string "Hello, world" with the last character missing. Here is some code:

```
//This function is called and the returned value is rendered into the page
export const renderNavBar = function() {
let searchBar = $('<input type="text" placeholder="Search for player here...">').keydown(handleSearchKeyPress);
let panel = $('<div></div>').append(searchBar);
return panel;
}

export const handleSearchKeyPress = function() {
let value = event.target.value;
console.log(value);
}
```

The value I consoled above would return "h" if I typed in "hi". Can anyone explain why and how I can get "hi" to show up?

Answer (score 1):

Update: I just needed to use the keyup function. The keydown function calls the existing bar before the key is released, and thus doesn't include the letter I intend it to include.